# Having trouble running SQL Queries in Python using Pyodbc library for persian words

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using Pyodbc library for saving some rows in a dataframe. However, the database I am trying to extract information from, has persian characters which has caused some problems.

Can anyone know how to solve the mentioned problem?

Comment: Are you inserting or selecting? Please show relevant code. Perhaps you need `nvarchar` rather than `varchar`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe what you mean by "some problems". FWIW, [this code](https://pastebin.com/Ze0C6bD8) works fine for me.

Comment: This is the code I have written but it seems that pyodbc can not figure out farsi words an d extract the wanted rows by "Select" command.         df = pd.read_sql_query('Select z from y where x = "تست"' , conn)
print(df)